# While getting Expired key on the Redis Listener unnecessary prefix is coming as Prefix?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis

�� t 677_BC getting this in the message but expected is 677_BC

```
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
    String channel = new String(message.getChannel());
    String body = new String(message.getBody());
    String expiredKey = message.toString();
    log.info("Received message on channel: ", channel,"The_Expired_RecurringKey_is::"+ expiredKey);
    String[] parts = expiredKey.split("_");
    Long recurringId = Long.parseLong(parts[0]);
    String suffix = parts[1];
    if(suffix.equals("BC")){
        // code for BC
    } else if(suffix.equals("PR")) {
        // Code for PR
    }
    log.info("Received message on channel: ", channel,"The_Expired_RecurringKey_is::"+ expiredKey);
}
```

677_BC this key is set to the Redis along with expiration, but im getting the key after expired as like this
�� t 677_BC , But Actual key should be this key -- 677_BC

please share me if one having idea About this one .